# How can I disable the scroll bars of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, scroll

how to disable the scroll bars of the page.

and disable this button.

[image]

Comment: From a UI point of view I do not like this question at all.  If I could not scroll with my wheel in your web page I would be a very upset user.  Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Possible issues: small screen/viewport (not every display device has 20480x5000 px, esp. mobile; and not everyone surfs with a maximized browser window anyway) won't show scrollbars *or* the relevant part of your content; also, what happens w/o JS enabled (e.g. NoScript)?

Comment: If you remove the scroll bars, the wheel problem goes away, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll(0,0);
});
```

If you want to use it you need to have jQuery imported.

Comment: So, this is jQuery?  You might want to add that as a tag.

Comment: Why import a complete remote library to get a thing that is natively available through plain Javascript and CSS?

Answer (score 31):

The scrollbars are a CSS issue.  You can add this to your page (or the inner part to a CSS file):

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: why should we give it for both html and body? Giving it to only html is not not sufficient?

Answer (score 7):

You can't disable that button (or any other method of scrolling the page); [see this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html). However, you could scrollTo(0,0) anytime you detect scrolling. This might look ugly (page scrolls a bit, then jumps back up).

For disabling the scrollbars, you can try setting `html, body { overflow: hidden }`; I think some browsers may not honor this.

(Wouldn't it be better to just create a page that fits into the viewport, so that the scrollbars aren't shown?)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.scroll = "no";
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
document.height = window.innerHeight;
```

should disable the scrollbars in most browsers.

See: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/3/10088543/how-to-disable-document-body-from-scrolling.aspx

Comment: @faresoft you still see a scrollbar despite trying each of those?

Answer (score 1):

I am making a mobile website, but I don't want it to be a whole bunch of webpages, so I am making it one page with scrolling disabled. I did this with

```
   <style>
   html, body {
   overflow: hidden;
   }
   </style>
```

Comment: Does your answer improve upon any existing answer? It's a specific use case?

Answer (score 1):

This will remove your scroll bar. [I did it by accident]

```
@media screen{        
body>div#header{        
position:fixed;        
}        
body>div#footer{        
position:fixed;        
} `
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: 
`* {overflow: hidden}` 
One problem I have when figuring it out was that I have a CSS drop-down (well slide across) menu on the page and that doesn't show when I use this method. I am still trying to figure out how to get the drop-down to work with this enabled.