# disable the vertical scrollbar of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to disable vertical scroll-bar (maybe also making it hidden) for all, except of an specific `div`:

**CSS**

```
#barra {
   display: none;
   height: calc(100% - 140px);
   margin: 0;
   overflow: auto;
   position: fixed;
   top: 90px;
}

#insidebarra {
   height: 800px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="barra">
   <div id="insidebarra"></div>
</div>
```

The scroll-bar  for `#barra` is not a problem, the problem is the scroll-bar of the page. And I don't know how can I disable it.

I searched but I found a lot of topics about **How to hide the scroll-bar**

Comment: @AlonEitan putting `overflow:hidden` will not just remove the scroll-bar, but also disables the page scroll, which I dont think is desired in this case

Comment: @Trix if you say that with css, hidding the scrollbar is possible also disable it ok... but i don't think this question is a suplicate because i think that the question you linked is only to hidden and not to disable... no ? thanks :)

Comment: @user3162975 here U R [How can I disable the scroll bars of a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611379/how-can-i-disable-the-scroll-bars-of-a-page)

Comment: @Trix you are right sorry.... ;)